# RadGrid with DetailTable giving Unspecified Error in JavaScript when clicking fast

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid, scriptresource.axd

I am using Internet Explorer 11 for testing:

I have a RadGrid control displaying list of Groups (groupId, groupName).
Each Group has a DetailTable displaying GroupMembers (memberId, groupId, memberName).

The RadGrid is placed in a ContentPage that belongs to a MasterPage.

In MasterPage there is RadAjaxManager. 
In the ContentPage I have RadAjaxManagerProxy having AjaxControlId refering to RadGrid, UpdatedControls refering to the same (RadGrid).

If I omit using Ajax things, working with full postback, the detail is expanded/collapsed correctly without errors.

However **when I use Ajax, the page returns an webpage error: Unspecified error.** It does not happen always but very often (about 80%). Everything is shown correctly, just getting that odd message.
When I use RadAjaxPanel instead of the proxied settings, the error is the same.

When I let the debugger show details, it crashes in **ScriptResource.axd** on line 835:
`var b=g.getBoundingClientRect();`

In the stack there is this calling:

```
$telerik.originalGetLocation [Line: 835, column: 2], ScriptResource.axd
commonScripts.getLocation [Line: 284, column: 2], ScriptResource.axd
commonScripts.getBounds [Line: 347, column: 25], ScriptResource.axd
$T.RadToolTip.prototype._getBoundsRelativeToElement [Line: 901, column: 19], ScriptResource.axd
$T.RadToolTip.prototype.getToolTipBounds [Line: 954, column: 54], ScriptResource.axd
Anonymous function [Line: 733, column: 81], ScriptResource.axd
Anonymous function [Line: 47, column: 9], ScriptResource.axd
$T.RadToolTip.prototype._playAnimation [Line: 740, column: 1], ScriptResource.axd
Anonymous function [Line: 667, column: 65], ScriptResource.axd
Anonymous function [Line: 47, column: 9], ScriptResource.axd
```

After some testing it seems to happen more often when I click fast to expand/collapse details (maybe there is not everything correctly loaded yet, but cannot get it). But it happens when I take my time and wait few secs between clicking, just not so often.

I searched the internet for some days, so far no success.
Web.config settings double checked, httphandlers are present correctly.

Please, suggest me some steps, cannot get over it.

Answer (score 0):

Got illuminated after sending, I finally asked right question uncle Google and found helping solution here:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/tooltip-inside-ajax-updatepanel#ygiEWdsUekuoLhx2AFwCHw

I is about interrupting running javascript function that handles tooltip showing using telerik RadTooltipManager when you click too early (before it happens).

**Setting ShowDelay="0" in RadTooltipManager solved my problem.** Hope it helps you too! :)

Comment: I forgot to clarify - when mouse got over the expand/collapse symbol, the tooltip started to show, while next click aborted running javascript function handling the tooltip showing and that was the right issue, not RadGrid itself.